# Sending email with attachment and using 'recipient-filename'

Tags: email, mu4e, attachment

I am using `message-send-and-exit` (with mu4e) to send an email with an attachment. I would like to rename the file so that in the email it appears with a different name than my local file. 
According to the [docs](http://www.gnus.org/manual/emacs-mime_11.html), I should be able to do that with `recipient-filename`. I also tried setting `name`.

```
<#part type="application/pdf" filename="old-name.pdf" recipient-filename="new-name.pdf" name="new-name.pdf" disposition=attachment>
<#/part>
```

However, upon testing, this doesn't seem to work. When I receive the email I get in the header

```
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="old-name.pdf"
Content-Description: old-name.pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="old-name.pdf"
```

What is the way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been solved with this [commit](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/commit/86c8582c9e4497406522c3073e232e1af2eb23d1), but I think it has not yet been released.